# How to detect if play back buttons are clicked in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, notifications, mediaplayback

I am using [CrossMediaManager](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager) to play mp3 files. Playing files works as exptected except that I want to allow users to open a specific page when they click on playback from the nofitication. I have not implemented notification, but I allowed to play media files in the background. In the attached picture, when a user click on the areas except those media buttons, I would like to open a specific page in my app.
Is there any way to handle if my app is opened from the notification area?

[image: Notification area]

Comment: Hi , if CrossMediaManager not supports that function, I think we can't get the notification callback . Unless customing a self-notification controller ,  and so can get the broadcast 
message form that .